# Duplicate rows so that all columns remain the same but one column gets sequentially larger

Tags: r

Working in R My current table looks like:

```
C1    C2                          C3
1     2011-02-01 04:30:00         4
2     2011-02-01 04:45:00         3
3     2011-02-01 05:00:00         5
4     2011-02-01 05:15:00         6
```

I wish it to look like this:

```
C1    C2                          C3       C4
1     2011-02-01 04:30:00         4        2011-02-01 04:30:00
2     2011-02-01 04:30:00         4        2011-02-01 04:35:00
3     2011-02-01 04:30:00         4        2011-02-01 04:40:00
4     2011-02-01 04:45:00         3        2011-02-01 04:45:00
5     2011-02-01 04:45:00         3        2011-02-01 04:50:00 
6     2011-02-01 04:45:00         3        2011-02-01 04:55:00
7     2011-02-01 05:00:00         5        2011-02-01 05:00:00
8     2011-02-01 05:00:00         5        2011-02-01 05:05:00
```

etc. etc. basically just want to make another column that goes up in five minute intervals but matches up with the intervals in C2. 
I was thinking something like the rep() function but that would mean the intervals in C2 are always consistent which they might not be. I am really looking for something that will do the five minute intervals based on what intervals are in C2.

Any help or feedback on the question would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: I think you need one more row based on the first row expansion as 'C3' is 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map2` to create a `list` column by taking the `seq`uence of `Datetime` converted 'C2' with `length` specified by the corresponding element of 'C3' `by` 5 minute intervals and `unnest` the `list` column

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(C4 = map2(lubridate::ymd_hms(C2), C3, ~ seq(.x, length.out = .y, by = '5 min'))) %>% 
  unnest
#  C1                  C2 C3                  C4
#1   1 2011-02-01 04:30:00  4 2011-02-01 04:30:00
#2   1 2011-02-01 04:30:00  4 2011-02-01 04:35:00
#3   1 2011-02-01 04:30:00  4 2011-02-01 04:40:00
#4   1 2011-02-01 04:30:00  4 2011-02-01 04:45:00
#5   2 2011-02-01 04:45:00  3 2011-02-01 04:45:00
#6   2 2011-02-01 04:45:00  3 2011-02-01 04:50:00
#7   2 2011-02-01 04:45:00  3 2011-02-01 04:55:00
#8   3 2011-02-01 05:00:00  5 2011-02-01 05:00:00
#9   3 2011-02-01 05:00:00  5 2011-02-01 05:05:00
#10  3 2011-02-01 05:00:00  5 2011-02-01 05:10:00
#11  3 2011-02-01 05:00:00  5 2011-02-01 05:15:00
#12  3 2011-02-01 05:00:00  5 2011-02-01 05:20:00
#13  4 2011-02-01 05:15:00  6 2011-02-01 05:15:00
#14  4 2011-02-01 05:15:00  6 2011-02-01 05:20:00
#15  4 2011-02-01 05:15:00  6 2011-02-01 05:25:00
#16  4 2011-02-01 05:15:00  6 2011-02-01 05:30:00
#17  4 2011-02-01 05:15:00  6 2011-02-01 05:35:00
#18  4 2011-02-01 05:15:00  6 2011-02-01 05:40:00
```

---

Or using `Map` from `base R`, get a `list` of sequences of DateTime with the same logic as above.  Expand the original dataset by `rep`licating the sequence of rows based on the `lengths` of the 'lst1' and create the new column 'C4'

```
lst1 <- Map(function(x, y) seq(x, length.out = y, by = '5 min'),
    as.POSIXct(df1$C2), df1$C3)
df2 <- df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), lengths(lst1)),]
df2$C4 <- do.call(c, lst1)
row.names(df2) <- NULL
```

---

If the condition is based on the next value of 'C2'

```
df1 %>% 
   mutate(C4 = map2(ymd_hms(C2), lubridate::ymd_hms(lead(C2, default = last(C2))),
        seq, by = '5 min')) %>%
   unnest %>% 
   group_by(C1) %>% 
   slice(-1)
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   C1 [3]
#     C1 C2                     C3 C4                 
#  <int> <chr>               <int> <dttm>             
#1     1 2011-02-01 04:30:00     4 2011-02-01 04:35:00
#2     1 2011-02-01 04:30:00     4 2011-02-01 04:40:00
#3     1 2011-02-01 04:30:00     4 2011-02-01 04:45:00
#4     2 2011-02-01 04:45:00     3 2011-02-01 04:50:00
#5     2 2011-02-01 04:45:00     3 2011-02-01 04:55:00
#6     2 2011-02-01 04:45:00     3 2011-02-01 05:00:00
#7     3 2011-02-01 05:00:00     5 2011-02-01 05:05:00
#8     3 2011-02-01 05:00:00     5 2011-02-01 05:10:00
#9     3 2011-02-01 05:00:00     5 2011-02-01 05:15:00
```

Or similar option using methods from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, C2 := as.POSIXct(C2)][, C4 := list(Map(seq, 
   MoreArgs = list(by = '5 min'), C2, shift(C2, type = 'lead',
      fill = last(C2))))][, unnest(.SD)][, .SD[-1], by = C1]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(C1 = 1:4, C2 = c("2011-02-01 04:30:00", "2011-02-01 04:45:00", 
"2011-02-01 05:00:00", "2011-02-01 05:15:00"), C3 = c(4L, 3L, 
 5L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The first method worked great but the second method is more along the lines of what I am after. However I keep getting this error:

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: wrong sign in 'by' argument.

I really can't work out what is causing the error so I thought you might have an idea?

Comment: @mathsnerd It should have worked.  May be some issue in the version of package.  Try `~seq(.x, .y, by = '5 min')`

Answer (score 1):

Another `tidyverse` option by using `complete`,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 mutate(C2 = as.POSIXct(C2, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), C4 = C2) %>% 
 complete(C4 = seq(min(C2), max(C2), by = '5 min')) %>% 
 fill(C1, C2, C3)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 4
>    C4                  C1    C2                     C3
>    <dttm>              <chr> <dttm>              <int>
>  1 2011-02-01 04:30:00 1     2011-02-01 04:30:00     4
>  2 2011-02-01 04:35:00 1     2011-02-01 04:30:00     4
>  3 2011-02-01 04:40:00 1     2011-02-01 04:30:00     4
>  4 2011-02-01 04:45:00 2     2011-02-01 04:45:00     3
>  5 2011-02-01 04:50:00 2     2011-02-01 04:45:00     3
>  6 2011-02-01 04:55:00 2     2011-02-01 04:45:00     3
>  7 2011-02-01 05:00:00 3     2011-02-01 05:00:00     5
>  8 2011-02-01 05:05:00 3     2011-02-01 05:00:00     5
>  9 2011-02-01 05:10:00 3     2011-02-01 05:00:00     5
> 10 2011-02-01 05:15:00 4     2011-02-01 05:15:00     6
> ```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a sequence of 5 min intervals between `min` and `max` values of `C2` and then do `left_join` on `df` and fill the missing values with previous value using `na.locf` from zoo.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

data.frame(C4 = seq(min(df$C2), max(df$C2), by = "5 min")) %>%
   left_join(transform(df, C4 = C2)) %>%
   na.locf()

#                    C4 C1                  C2 C3
#1  2011-02-01 04:30:00  1 2011-02-01 04:30:00  4
#2  2011-02-01 04:35:00  1 2011-02-01 04:30:00  4
#3  2011-02-01 04:40:00  1 2011-02-01 04:30:00  4
#4  2011-02-01 04:45:00  2 2011-02-01 04:45:00  3
#5  2011-02-01 04:50:00  2 2011-02-01 04:45:00  3
#6  2011-02-01 04:55:00  2 2011-02-01 04:45:00  3
#7  2011-02-01 05:00:00  3 2011-02-01 05:00:00  5
#8  2011-02-01 05:05:00  3 2011-02-01 05:00:00  5
#9  2011-02-01 05:10:00  3 2011-02-01 05:00:00  5
#10 2011-02-01 05:15:00  4 2011-02-01 05:15:00  6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
```

you can use this library package. Convert df[C2] as date time either using `apply()` or directly assigning this to date time.
once it is converted then use either

`df[C4] <-  ymd_hms(df[C2]) + min(5)` or  `df[C4] <- ymd_hms(df[C2]) + seconds(300)`